# How to use nonce in IIS for content security policy?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, content-security-policy

I have MVC application developed in ASP.NET 4.5.1. The application is using javascripts in several pages. Some of the javascripts are referenced as

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/js")
```

and also there are some inline scripts like

```
<script type="javascript">

   // javascript code
</script>
```

I want to implement `Content Security Policy` for this site. The site is hosted in IIS. So in IIS i add `content-security-policy` header in `HTTP Response Header` as

```
 object-src 'none';
 script-src 'nonce-{random}' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:;
 base-uri 'self';
 report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/<unique_id>/<application_version>
```

So every response will include this header.

**Questions**
 1. Should `nonce` attribute only recommended for inline scripting?
 2. How do i add randomly generated`nonce` into `script` tags and importantly how IIS would know randomly generated nonce value so it can include in response header? (i am assuming every response will have unique nonce value)

Answer (score 3):

1. `nonce` attribute only used for inline scripts. If you want to take secure your sources from other origins, you can use `hash`
2. IIS does not provide nonce generation as default. You need to handle it on the backend.

   i. Define a helper to generate a random nonce string, named `CreateNonce()`. The string length is not so important but you need to be sure it's a unique value. So, if you define a 10-20 length string with alphanumeric characters, it will be okay. You will call this method on your Views, where are your inline scripts. eg: `<script <%CreateNonce()%>`
   When you call this helper, it will return an output that generated nonce value, eg.`<script nonce-123abc>` and call another helper which is explained on the following step.

   ii.  Define another helper to create CSP rules to Response Header for inline scripts, named `CSPGenerator()`. When you call this method, it should create a `Content-Security-Policy` response header if it does not exist. If the header is exist, it should append the new nonce value to that.

Pseudocode (sorry, I am not an asp.net developer);

```
Views.cshtml 

<script <%CreateNonce()%> >

Helpers.cs

Public CreateNonce(){
generateRandomAlphaNumericChars
CSPGenerator('apply-to-csp-rules:generateRandomAlphaNumericChars')
and response.write generateRandomAlphaNumericChars
}

Public CSPGenerator(str nonce_){
GetHttpResponse[csp],
if null, add new response header,
response.header.append="script-src "+ nonce_
}
```